# Can TI chip CC2540 be used for mobile phone access with bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microchip

I want to use Ti chip cc2540 for communicating with a mobile phone. I'm not familiar with this kind of chips.
""
What I found is this: http://cn.mouser.com/ticc2540/ it said "Texas Instruments CC2540 2.4 GHz Bluetooth® SoC" "Mobile Phone Accessories".

Anyone who have done something with this chip ?

If it cannot, what else chip can be used to communicating with mobile phone via bluetooth ?

Comment: I think your question is placed on the wrong site. Check: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CC2540 is a Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) chip.  This is a new mode of Bluetooth, part of the 4.0 standard.  The LE mode is **NOT** compatible with previous Bluetooth standards.  The only phone on the market that has an LE capable chip is the iPhone 4S.  Soon, all new phones will start to support BT LE.  The chip in the iPhone is dual mode so it can do regular BT and BT LE.  The TI CC2540 can only do the new LE mode.

Comment: The CC256x does 'regular' Bluetooth, see e.g. http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/CC256x

Answer (score 2):

The CC2540 does work with the iphone 4s and in fact, TI has provided an example xcode project to prove it.  Read about it on their wiki: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Category:IPhone4SBLEDemo#App_Operation

Bluegiga also has a module that uses this chip and comes with a wrapper protocol to use their own development language.